# How to access to row if cell is clicked in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have table which looks this way.

[image]

When I click on change button I want to change innerHTML of second cell in the row  to `<input>{this.props.keywords}</input>` and change icon change to another one (I think it's basically the same issue). What is correct way to access content of this cell?

```
class Contenttr extends Component {
  deleteItem() {
    this.props.onDeleteItem(this.props.id);
  }
  changeItem() {

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td className="text-center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x50" alt="Logo" /></td>
        <td className="text-center">{this.props.keywords}</td>
        <td className="text-center">{this.props.place}</td>
        <td className="text-center"><Button color="danger" size="sm" onClick={this.deleteItem.bind(this)}>Delete</Button></td>
        <td className="text-center"><Button color="primary" size="sm" onClick={this.changeItem.bind(this)}>Change</Button></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    trStore: state
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    onDeleteItem: (id) => {
      dispatch({type:"DELETE_ITEM", id: id})
    }
  })
)(Contenttr);
```

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is change the backing data structure for your rows based on the id of the item that was clicked similar to how you are trying to do for deleting an item.

```
changeItem() {
  this.props.onChangeItem(this.props.id);
}
```

Then in your reducer, if the backing array for these table rows is called `items`, you can do something like this to change the `place` of that item to `"foo"`

```
const itemToChangeIndex = items.findIndex(item => item.id === action.id);
return items.slice()[itemToChangeIndex].place = "foo";
```

Comment: wouldn't it change the content of place? I need jut to change content of cell for a time

Comment: In that case you can update the components local state instead using this.setState and have some kind of array or object that keeps track of what has changed and then reflect that in your render method.